# Proper way to upload file to server with Android volley

Tags: android, file-upload, server, android-volley

I want to upload a file via an Android App to a server (django) by utilizing the Volley library.

All approaches I've seen converted the file to a string and then sent it via Volley or they used some legacy libary to send the file. I am highly doubtful that this a good approach for this task.

So, how does one upload a file (not just an image) from Android to a server in 2019 in a proper and efficient manner?

Thanks in advance!